# Pass variables between step definitions in Cucumber groovy

Tags: groovy, cucumber-jvm

I am wondering how we can pass variables between two step definitions files.

I found this [How to share variables across multiple cucumber step definition files with groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099934/how-to-share-variables-across-multiple-cucumber-step-definition-files-with-groov) but their structure is different from mine, because I am not using classes in step definition.

The following is my two step definition files.

**Feature File 1**

```
Scenario: Consumer registration
    When I try to register with my details with "memberNo" mem no.
    Then I should be able to get success response
```

**stepDef1**

```
When(~'^I try to register with my details with "([^"]*)" mem no.$') { String memdNo ->
   sMemdNo  = memNo + getRanNo()
   // more code here
}
```

**Feature File 2**

```
Scenario: Event Generation
    When I activate my account
    Then I can see the file having "logName" event
```

**stepDef2**

```
Then(~'^I can see the file having "([^"]*)" event$') { String logName ->
   eventFile = GetLogtData(logName , sMemdNo )
   // more code here 
}
```

So, as per the above I want to get the value of `sMemdNo` from `stepDef1` and use it in `stepDef2`.

Comment: Can you post your feature file?

Comment: Why do you not want to use classes? That would seem the obvious way to preserve information between related steps.

Comment: @Selena Sorry for the delay update, I have added the two feature files to the question.

Comment: @BarrySW19 I am not used to do that way. Is there any other alternative? Or that's is the best way you reckon.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that you use the World, to store global variables needed across step definitions. 
You can see an example here: [cucumber-jvm-groovy-example](https://github.com/dkowis/cucumber-jvm-groovy-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/calc/CalculatorSteps.groovy).
You can combine the World with a Factory and/or dependency injection pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To use variables between steps you can add the variable at the top of the steps file (groovy or java), and the variable used in one step will have the value available for other variable.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYNVr.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZbVk.png)

Comment: I think, better if you provide some examples

Comment: Hi @mrEvgenX!
I mean to pass the variable as explained in the image above